# Add new choices on EntityType

Tags: doctrine, jquery-select2, symfony5

I am building a form for adding tags using select2 with Symfony forms. It works when selecting choices from the database, but it doesn't when adding new ones (which are created on-the-fly within the event subscriber.

The form type:

```
    ->add('tags', EntityType::class, [
      'class' => Tag::class,
      'required' => false,
      'label' => 'Tags (optional)',
      'multiple' => true,
      'mapped' => false,
      'label_attr' => ['class' => 'control-label font-weight-bold'],
      'attr' => ['class' => 'border js-tags-input', 'placeholder' => 'Enter tags'],
      'choices' => $editedObject->getTags(),
      'data' => $editedObject->getTags(),
      'choice_label'  => 'name',
   ])
   ->addEventSubscriber(new TagsSubscriber($this->entityManager));
```

The event subscriber:

```
class TagsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {

        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }


    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'preSubmit'];
    }

    public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if(isset($event->getData()['tags'])){

            $choices = [];

            foreach ($event->getData()['tags'] as $tagInput) {
                $tagFromDB = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Tag::class)->findOneByIdOrName($tagInput);

                if ($tagFromDB) {
                    $choices[$tagInput] = $tagFromDB;

                } else {
                    $tag = new Tag();
                    $tag->setName($tagInput);
                    $this->entityManager->persist($tag);
                    $this->entityManager->flush();

                    $choices[$tagInput] = $tag;
                }
            }

            $form->add('tags', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Tag::class,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Tags (optional)',
                'multiple' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
                'choices' => $choices,
                'data' => $choices,
            ]);

            $form->setData($data);

            return;
        }

    }
}
```

New tags are created correctly, but they won't associate to the related entity, and I get the following error when I submit the form:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\Entity\Tag could not be
>   converted to string

Can someone point me to the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: Try changing the line `$choices[$tagInput] = $tag;` to `$choices[$tagInput] = $tag->getName();`, although I think it should be different.

Comment: @MartinM. I got the same error

Comment: Does it say in which line? At the very least it should have been a different error.

Comment: @MartinM. nope, just the same message, thrown on the $form->createView() method.

Comment: Have you tried just adding a `__toString()` method in your Tag entity? Something like `public function __toString() { return $this->name }`.

Comment: @ehymel I've added that method, and now when I try adding a new value I get this error on the form: "Unable to reverse value for property path "tags": Could not find all matching choices for the given values."

Comment: The value shown on the error trace is a string, not the related id. Thus the validation is done before the code of the subscriber. Should I do any changes on PRE_SET_DATA or any other event?

Comment: Why do you have the option `mapped => false`? I think that should be set to `true`.

Comment: @ehymel I fixed that, but I'm getting the same error

Comment: I think you should also remove the `data` parameter.

Comment: @ehymel thanks, but it's still returning the same error